# IOError: closed stream in irb

Tags: ruby, file-io, io, irb, ioerror

```
File.open("/tmp/test") do |file|
  file.each_line("e") {|line|
    puts "Got #{ line.dump }"
  }
end
```

returns "IOError: closed stream" in irb. But if is is saved in file 'test.rb', `ruby test.rb` - works fine. Ruby versions: ruby-2.0.0-p247, ruby-2.1.0-preview1, Ubuntu, Mac OS. What do I wrongly?

```
user:ads user$ echo "a\nb\nc" > /tmp/test
user:ads user$ irb
2.1.0-preview1 :001 > File.open("/tmp/test") { |file| file.each_line { |line| puts "Got #{ line.dump }" } }
Got "a\\nb\\nc\n"
IOError: closed stream
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/formatter.rb:199:in `directory?'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/formatter.rb:199:in `awesome_file'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/formatter.rb:26:in `format'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb:137:in `unnested'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb:104:in `awesome'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/kernel.rb:10:in `ai'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/kernel.rb:20:in `ap'
    from /Users/user/.irbrc:7:in `output_value'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/bin/irb:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: See [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IOError.html),to get the idea when such an error may come.But I don't see any such symptom in your code.

Comment: Does file `"/tmp/test"` exist?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes..Otherwise `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory` must be thrown!

Comment: Its working for me as well.

Comment: Type the code in your irb.. and show us that content,with error altogether.....Let us check!

Comment: It looks like awesome_print breaks code. I turned it off and all works fine. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix in https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print/pull/141

```
- ls = File.directory?(f) ? `ls -adlF #{f.path.shellescape}` : `ls -alF #{f.path.shellescape}`
+ ls = `ls -adlF #{f.path.shellescape}`
```